# Error in Qt Creator: "The environment variable ExtensionSdkDir is not set"

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am trying to build my project using the Visual Studio compiler in Qt Creator, but whenever I run the program the following error appears:

```
qt.winrtrunner: Using the Appx profile.
qt.winrtrunner: The environment variable ExtensionSdkDir is not set.
qt.winrtrunner: The directory "" does not exist.
```

EDIT: I have tried to add a "ExtensionSdkDir" in the build environment setting it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs". Then the following error occurs

```
qt.winrtrunner: Using the Appx profile.
qt.winrtrunner: Failed to activate application: 0x80073cf1 "Package was not found."
```

Comment: I have tried to run the project in Visual Studio and it works, but I can't seem to make it work in Qt Creator. This is really frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution to the problem. I set "ExtensionSdkDir" in the build environment to "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs`".
Then I noticed that I did not enable "Developer Mode" in Windows 10 Settings (Update and security), enabling this function resolved the issue.